# Changing PDF blend mode (transparency) in LuaTeX node list

Tags: luatex, pdf, transparency, blend-mode

How can I set transparency/opacity in LuaTeX node list processing?

In my case I'd like to set the blend mode for a rule/rectangle. I tried the following:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\directlua{
    local function test ( head )
        for n in node.traverse_id ( node.id ( "disc" ), head ) do
            head = node.insert_before ( head, n, node.new ( "whatsit", "pdf_literal" ) )
            n.prev.mode = 0
            n.prev.data = "q 10 0 obj << /Type /Page /Resources 20 0 R >> endobj 20 0 obj << /ExtGState << /GS1 30 0 R >> >> endobj 30 0 obj << /Type /ExtGState /BM Overlay >> endobj /GS1 gs 1 .25 .45 rg 0 -.5 m 0 6.5 l -6 6.5 l -6 -.5 l f Q"
        end
        return head
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "pre_linebreak_filter", test, "test" )
}
\begin{document}
\Large
movement
\end{document}
```

Without success.

Can this perhaps be implemented with a pdf_colorstack whatsit?

(I'm not sure if this is perhaps a pure PDF question that has nothing to do with LuaTeX. But maybe there is something specific about doing this in a LuaTeX node list, so I'll ask the question here.)

Comment: you can't add objects simply inside the stream. And you can't invent numbers like 10 or 20 for them. They must be properly reserved and referenced. You obviously don't know a lot about pdf and about the needed primitives. So why are you trying to do this manually instead of using the interfaces from e.g. transparent or l3opacity or tikz?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because this is going to be part of a package that (so far) operates solely on node list level.

Comment: well that won't work. For transparency you also have to add objects. And if you add values to the ExtGState dictionary or the page resources you must do it in a managed way if you don't want to break other packages like tikz or transparency which use them too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay.. too bad. I would not have thought that transparency is such a big deal. … But it is bearable that I do without it.